# Incrementing 'masked' bitsets

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, intrinsics

I'm currently in the process of writing a tree enumerator where I've come across the following problem:

I'm looking at masked bitsets, i.e. bitsets where the set bits are a subset of a mask, i.e. `0000101` with mask `1010101`. What I want to accomplish is increment the bitset, but only with respect to the masked bits. In this example, the result would be `0010000`. To make it a bit clearer, extract only the masked bits, i.e. `0011`, increment them to `0100` and distribute them to the mask bits again, giving `0010000`.

Does anybody see an efficient way to do this, short of implementing the operation by hand using a combination of bitscans and prefix masks?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just fill the non mask bits with ones so that they propagate carry:

```
// increments x on bits belonging to mask
x = ((x | ~mask) + 1) & mask;
```

Comment: That's a nice trick...Almost the magic I said there is none :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Never believe it's not so.

Comment: Presumably not important to OP since they accepted, but it perhaps should be noted that this will zero the non-mask bits. If they _were_ needed elsewhere, you'd have to be more careful replacing `x`.  Possibly `x = (x & ~mask) | (((x | ~mask) + 1) & mask);`.

Comment: @TripeHound If they weren't needed, what would be the point of even using a bit mask?

Comment: @someonewithpc Not sure what you're trying to say/ask. I don't know _why_ the OP needs to increment a non-adjacent set of bits, so I don't know whether the _other_ bits in the original value matter or not. E.g. if the original value were `0101101` (e.g. `.1.1.0.` in the non-mask bits and `0.0.1.1` in the "counter") would they _need_ `0111000` (a new "counter" of `0.1.0.0` while preserving `.1.1.0.`) or is just `0010000` acceptable. This answer (and probably others, though I've not checked) give the latter; my version should give the former if that is what's required.

Answer (score 21):

While not intuitive compared to the accepted answer, this works in only 3 steps:

```
x = -(x ^ mask) & mask;
```

This can be verified as suggested by zch:

```
  -(x ^ mask)
= ~(x ^ mask) + 1  // assuming 2's complement
= (x ^ ~mask) + 1
= (x | ~mask) + 1  // since x and ~mask have disjoint set bits
```

Then it becomes equivalent to the accepted answer.

Comment: The answer by zch is very intuitive, I can immediately see it is right because of his clear explanation. What is the logic of this answer? How does this formula work out to give the desired effect? I am curious about the process of discovery, the nature of the insight here.

Comment: I think your verification would be much simpler if you just proved that `-(x ^ mask) == (x | ~mask) + 1` whenever x is a subset of mask and then referred to my answer.

Comment: `-(x^mask) == ~((x ^ mask) - 1) == ~(x ^ mask) + 1 == (x ^ ~mask) + 1 == (x | ~mask) + 1`. Last equation holds because bitsets are disjoint, others are always true (at least in 2-complement).

Comment: Those who are curious about the steps I took to derive this answer can refer to [this page](https://nleeshong.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/bit-manipulation-1/).

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that these don't optimize the same, which is often relevant to people doing bit-twiddling: https://godbolt.org/g/7VWXas - although which one is actually shorter seems to depend on the compiler. No idea which one would be *faster* or if the difference is significant.

Answer (score 8):

If the order of iteration is not that important, and a decrement operation will satisfy your needs, it is possible to  use only two operations:

Let's start with

`x = mask`

and get previous value with

`x = (x - 1) & mask`

`x - 1` part changes the last non-zero bit to zero, and sets all less significant bits to 1's. Then `& mask` part leaves only mask bits among them.

Comment: 2 ops, nice. I'd argue however that it is the same approach, only propagating borrow through zeros, rather than carry through ones.

Comment: @zch, that's right, thanks. I'll rephrase the answer

Comment: only works if x starts with all the non-mask bits clear.

Comment: @Jasen, sure. But it's not difficult to set those non-mask bits. And other answers have the similar issue.